# Transform Array ["1", "3", "2"] to [132]

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
["1", "3", "2"]["2", "3", "1"]["3", "1", "2"]...
```

And want to transform it to an array that looks like this:

```
[132][231]..
```

What can i do? Thanks!

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [["1", "3", "2"],["2", "3", "1"],["3", "1", "2"]]
a.map{|e| [e.join.to_i]}
# => [[132], [231], [312]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html), [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join), and [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
a = ["1", "3", "2"],["2", "3", "1"],["3", "1", "2"]
a.map { |x| x.join.to_i } # => [132, 231, 312]
a.map { |x| [x.join.to_i] } # => [[132], [231], [312]]
```

Comment: your array is not valid,and the output is not as OP said..

Comment: its OK.. technically I came first with the OP said output.. then :))

Comment: @LBg, I rolled back your change.

Comment: @falsetru, Indeed. It was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure yourself that your variable has correct format and then as said

```
a = [["1", "3", "2"],["2", "3", "1"],["3", "1", "2"]]
a.map do |x|
    x.join.to_i 
end
```